# Azure Function C# 'Run' is inaccessible due to its protection level 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions but am attempting to call a c# file and method from the function. The "Run.csx" file itself is saying it is inaccessible due to the security level.

Azure run file:

```
using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
Integration.Run.ImportRosters(
    log: s => log.Info(s),
    connectionString: "conString",
    siteID: 5,
    nowUtc: DateTime.UtcNow,
    ActualDays: 7,
    RosterDays: 7     
);
log.Info($"Import Roster Data function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

And its calling this c# function:

```
namespace Integration
{
public static class Run
{
    private static readonly TimeZoneInfo NewZealand = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time");

    public static void ImportRosters(
        Action<string> log,
        string connectionString,
        int siteID,
        DateTime nowUtc,
        int actualDays,
        int rosterDays
        )
    {

        var adminDatabase = new HospoIQ_AdminDBContext();
        var settings = adminDatabase.Settings.ToList();
        var localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowUtc, NewZealand);
        log($"Roster Data import function executed at: {localDateTime}");
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I am in the belief that it is an error with my code on the Azure side as it doesn't even reach my c# code.

Error Message:

```
[Error] Function compilation error 
2018-02-25T21:31:07.467 [Error] run.csx(10,5): error CS0149: Method name expected
2018-02-25T21:31:07.467 [Error] run.csx(11,33): error CS0122: 'Run' is inaccessible due to its protection level
2018-02-25T21:31:07.526 [Error] Exception while executing function: 
Functions.ImportRosterData. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Script compilation failed.2018-02-25T21:31:07.698 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=08508394-4d6b-4cb0-a9e7-9479a017df05, Duration=289ms)
```

Comment: The function `ImportRosters` and it's enclosing class are not complete, is that the whole file?

Comment: Hello. Its not the entire file as its quite long and didnt need to go and post it all i believed. but even putting a log at the very top it doesnt reach it

Comment: What is the name of the other file and do you have `load` directive to use one from the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a number of problems in your code sample:

- No `load` directive in `Run.csx`
- Namespaces are not allowed in C# script files
- Parameter names of the called method do not match (e.g. `ActualDays` vs `actualDays`)
- (recommended) Don't call your helper class `Run` not to confuse it with `Run` of the Function

Below is a complete working example that you should base your implementation on.

`Integration.csx`:

```
public static class Integration
{
    private static readonly TimeZoneInfo NewZealand = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time");

    public static void ImportRosters(
        Action<string> log,
        string connectionString,
        int siteID,
        DateTime nowUtc,
        int actualDays,
        int rosterDays
        )
    {
        var localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowUtc, NewZealand);
        log($"Roster Data import function executed at: {localDateTime}");
    }
}
```

`Run.csx`:

```
#load "Integration.csx"

using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    Integration.ImportRosters(
        log: s => log.Info(s),
        connectionString: "conString",
        siteID: 5,
        nowUtc: DateTime.UtcNow,
        actualDays: 7,
        rosterDays: 7     
    );
    log.Info($"Import Roster Data function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I‘m not 100% sure, but I think that the error means, that the static class `Run` was inaccessible, not the `Run` method of your function.

According to [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#reusing-csx-code) you’ll have to load your .csx file with the `#load` directive in order to use it

```
#load "integration.csx"
```